# how to reduce 32 v dc to 24 v

Tags: voltage

I need to monitor a 32v battery bank and operate a switching circuit I've found when the maximum charge is reached. The switching circuit only has an operating range of 5 - 24v. 
How can I easily (simple, nothing fancy) reduce the input voltage from the battery bank to this circuit's operating range?

Comment: What current do you need?

Comment: simplest is linear regulator, but they get hot, depending on load size..

Comment: Everything in EE is fancy.  If you had static current demands the easiest way would be a resistor, but often this is not the case.  You need a voltage regulator circuit.

Answer (score 1):

If you need (or just want) high efficiency, a [buck converter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter) may be what you need. Briefly, a buck converter uses a switching transistor and an inductor to provide steady current while lowering the voltage at the output.

Something like [this](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/VHB75W-Q48-S24/102-2256-ND/2162717) may help, though the one I linked is pretty expensive, and I am sure you could search for a buck converter that suits your needs and might cost less.

Answer (score 0):

How much current do you need?

There are several possible techniques that you can use.

1) Use a SMPS to drop the input voltage to the correct value.  Depending upon *which* SMPS power supply you use, you can take several Amps from the 24V output.

2) Place a 8.2V Zener diode in series with the 32V rail.  This can be good for anywhere from a few mA to perhaps several hundred mA, depending upon the size of the Zener diode.  A 5W Zener diode would be good for 500 mA or better.

Comment: I unsure of the current required for the threshold switching circuit. I can't find any info. The circuit operates a 12v pcb mounted 5 amp dpdt relay when the desired voltage is met. I've been doing some digging in the middle of typing this and have discovered that the relay has a 30ma coil with 400 ohm resistance.

Comment: So do I understand that you have 32V available, and you want to reduce it so you can use it to energize the coil of a relay? If the relay coil is 400 Ohms, and it works from 5V to 24V, just put a resistor in series with the relay coil. But you should also update your original question to include this information and a link to the relay specifications. Then someone can calculate the resistor value and power dissipation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a decent solution for moderate current:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuZOJo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The TIP31C needs a small heatsink. You can draw more current if you increase the size of the heatsink, but it doesn't make sense to use a linear regulator if it's going to waste all that energy.

If you care about the wasted energy, a considerably more complex but more efficient solution would be something like this:

[image]

Both those circuit can withstand transients in the 90V range at the input, so they're pretty safe. An ordinary LM7824 regulator is rated for 40V (absolute maximum) at the input and would be very simple, but that is not a lot of safety margin.